Can I put all of these wires in one junction box?
I opened up the wall because there was an electrical plate about 3 inches above the lighting fixture and it looked messy (I’m redoing the bathroom). However, I was not expecting to see the mess/confusion behind the walls. Does anyone have a theory as to what this all is. The top box contains two old cloth wires attached to two newer wires, and they are capped, and were covered with a plate. The wires below the box seem to be unrelated and were not in a junction box - they were fished through the drywall and were running power to my vanity light (I certainly didn’t do this!). This seems not to code - am I right? I guess my question is 1) can I put both sets of wires in ONE junction box - include the wires that go to the vanity light and the mystery wires? It seems odd to place a junction box above a junction box. I’ll hire an electrician if this gets too complicated.


Can you describe the 4th photo?  I have no idea what I'm looking at.

If in the US, that light needs a box.
You should be able to place all the wires in the new box for the light, if those wires are long enough to fit.
The cables must fit enough to have about a 1/4 inch of cable past the cable clamps.  You also need about 6 inches of wire from the cable clamp.
Should see if both sets are on the same breaker.  While two breaker circuits can be in the same box, a person needs to know about the second breaker to be safe.

The question author is unlikely to know what "long enough" means for rules in the USA.  Could you expand this answer?

Thanks! I checked and all of the wires are on the same breaker.

Usually when you have a junction box connecting older wires to newer ones near a light fixture or near anything recent, it is because power is coming from the old wires, and they were not long enough to reach the desired location. So here, guessing, there was a bathroom renovation, the vanity light was desired where it is, the old cloth wires couldn't reach. Rather than rip up the walls and install all new wires, they put in a junction box and extend them with newer wires. The junction box cannot be hidden in the wall, hence the cover plate.
The only thing really wrong there is that there should be a round junction box behind the vanity light. The newer cables should terminate in that box and the light should be attached to the box rather than the cable is just poking through the drywall.
If you are renovating the bathroom this is a good opportunity to replace the very old cloth cables and redo all the wiring properly.  Remove as much drywall as you have to, to essentially replace all the wiring in the bathroom.  If you have an unfinished basement and can fish new cable from there, you can fully replace all the wiring. It will eat into your renovation budget a little bit but this is your only chance and you should take it.

This is what I thought was going on until I opened up the wall a bit. The vanity light is not in any way connected to the junction box above. There is plenty of slack in the wires above and could have easily reached the vanity light. It’s really perplexing. There is an odd quirk with my bathroom - the lightswich must be on for the outlet to work. So maybe there’s an extra set of wires that has something to do with that? When I had an electrician here last, I asked if he could fix this, and he said it would be very expensive as wires would have to be run to the breaker box.

Fascinating.   The only way to tell why old wires are where they are is to completely remove all the drywall, and even then you have to use some imagination.  In mine I  found two door frames hidden in the walls to two other adjacent rooms, with all kinds of old wiring related to previous uses of the room.  It was not always a bathroom. Again, if you are doing more than painting and replacing hardware, you should use this opportunity to decommission all old wiring and do it new the way you want.

I decided to disconnect the mystery wires, cap them, and turn the power box on to see if they’re live and doing something useful. They ARE somehow related to the vanity light... yet they go way into the wall and so are connected somewhere else down the line. My neighbor caused serious water damage last year and a foot of wall all the way around was removed by the mold remediation people. It never occurred to me to update the wiring. I want to move soon because my neighbor is a nightmare (6 water incidents thus far). If this were my forever home then I’d replace all the wiring.
